# Copy or Export template of a Bot Framework Composer bot?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

Is there any way to copy a bot that was created in Botframework composer?

Essentially, we have a bot and we want to create a variant of it. I'd be happy with exporting a template that someone could load so they don't have to re-create all the basic dialogs.

I've tried just copying the folder but there are just too many dependencies to try to rename everything.

But it's just too much work to enter all the dialogs again manually.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you say you tried copying the folder, which folder? The entire bot folder? That should work. Please give a bit more info on what you were trying to rename, etc.

Comment: Yes, copying the entire folder works. It creates a clone of the entire solution. But this causes some confusion because everything is named exactly the same. The process of renaming the solution and the bot manually is difficult. So I'm looking for a way to rename the clone and the bot so when someone is working on it, it's clear that this is not Bot1 but Bot2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Encapsulate what you want to reuse in a dialog(try to keep everything you really need outside of the main dialog, main lg and main lu)
2. Create a new bot with a new name
3. Copy over the dialogs to reuse and call them or the main one from the root dialog of the new bot. (Copy all the dialogs inside of the dialogs folder into the new project)

That should work.

Never played with it but creating a package with those subdialogs and adding it to the new bot would also work. Then you can tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

> The process of renaming the solution and the bot manually is difficult. So I'm looking for a way to rename the clone and the bot so when someone is working on it, it's clear that this is not Bot1 but Bot2

Ok, I see. Unfortunately, there is no built-in or easy way to do this. Opening the bot folder in something like Visual Studio Code or other editor and using a find/replace function is, (again; unfortunately), the best option.